# How to create a 3D pseudosphere (tractrix) with Matlab with meshgrid() and surf()

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I use Matlab once or twice every other year, so please let me know if the question is not good enough to stay, and I will erase it, but I checked the dimensions of the three columns in S below, and I am not sure why it wouldn't work, so if you can give a tip on what's going on in terms of linear algebra types of structures in the code, I will be very appreciative.

This is what I want (more or less):

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
v = linspace(0,2*pi);
w = linspace(0,5);
x = cos(v)./cosh(w);
y = sin(v)./cosh(w);
[x,y] = meshgrid(v,w);
z = w - tanh(w);
S = [x;y;z];
h = surf(x,y,z)
set(h,'edgecolor','none')
colormap summer
```

This is the error:

```
Error using surf (line 71)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

Which I thought it was after being concatenated to the other two columns in S.

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization works like this:

```
a = 0.3;

u = 0:0.01:(2 * pi);
v = 0:0.01:5;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(u,v);

x = a.* cos(X) ./ cosh(Y);
y = a.* sin(X) ./ cosh(Y);
z = a.* (Y - tanh(Y));

h = surf(x,y,z);
zlim([0, 0.9]);
set(h,'edgecolor','none')
colormap summer
```

[image]